# What's causing excessive Datastore Write Operations (even whan they're disabled!)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a (wicket-based) webapp that has an auto-refreshing panel (it refreshes once in 5 seconds). My Datastore Write Operations count was rising about 5% a hour (so ~2500 ops/hour). However Appstat is showing only datastore_v3.RunQuery operations, which is the expected behavior. Where are these write operations coming from?

To investigate the issue, I disabled Datastore Writes from Application Settings. I started getting the following warning to the log:

```
2013-01-31 10:17:53.672
/wicket/
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CapabilityDisabledException: The API call datastore_v3.Put() is temporarily unavailable: Datastore writes have been disabled by an application administrator. Writes can be re-enabled in the admin console.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:487)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:392)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:781)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:823)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.success(RpcStub.java:808)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:898)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:803)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1092)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:940)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:2300)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:2101)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$2100(RpcNetChannel.java:145)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:3171)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:614)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:417)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$ClientAdapter.receivedMessage(UdrpcTransport.java:425)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.dispatchPacket(UdrpcTransport.java:266)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.readPackets(UdrpcTransport.java:218)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$1.run(UdrpcTransport.java:82)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:578)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:1002)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:884)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:136)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl$WorkerThread.run(EventManagerImpl.java:1855)
```

Does this mean something is trying a write operation? As you can see, there are no classes from my application in the stack.

What's even stranger, my Write Operation quota has grown 2% even during this time (about an hour) I have had Write Operations disabled! How can that be?

Comment: Are you sure appstats isn't doing it ?

Comment: Appstats traces also itself and is showing only memcache.Gets. After I posted this question, Write Operations have again risen another 1%. All this while I have had Write Operations disabled! Isn't there any way to get a more precise trace what is happening in my DB?

Comment: Do you have sessions enabled? The session object is updated in DB on every request.

Comment: Yes I do, and I was starting to suspect sessions myself. But shouldn't session update be rather cheap in DB, regardless of session object size (it gets serialized into one entity attribute)?